# PrintWriter java don`t print Russian text Android

Tags: java, android

My code

```
String Text = "Обсуживает = " + WaiterName + "\n" + 
               "Дата и время = "+timeStamp + "\n" + 
               "Стол " +NameNeka+ "\n" + " Заказ = ";

 try {
      Socket sock = new Socket("192.168.1.104", 9100);
      sock.getOutputStream().write(Text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
      PrintWriter oStream = new PrintWriter(
           new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8), 
           true
      );
      oStream.println(Text);
      oStream.println("\n\n\n\f");
      oStream.close();
      sock.close();
 } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

When I click print it shows Russia text "?". How to fix it?
And I need only Russian text

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of all string values

Comment: Your code should result in proper cyrillic letters (both version, i.e. with and without the PrintWriter). What's at the other end of the connection where you observe the text? Are you sure it is set for UTF-8?